# Car Starting Itself

Tags: starting, subaru, impreza

I've got a 2010 Subaru Impreza with an automatic car starter that's been installed for about 3 years.

For some reason, the car has started itself twice in the past couple of hours, for no apparent reason. The fob is on my counter (i.e. no way the button has been pressed).

Is this definitely a problem with the automatic car starter, or could it be a deeper issue with the car?

Comment: Disable / disconnect the car starter- remove the supply fuse and see if it continues...

Comment: Replace the battery in the fob - a marginal battery might have some odd effects.  But by all means do this *after* the suggestion from @SolarMike

Answer (score 3):

If it looks like a duck...

Without physically seeing the car I'd be 99% certain that this is to do with the automatic starter. I've **never** see a car without auto-start technology do this (OEM or otherwise) and aftermarket tech that affects when a car is running, be it an auto-start, or turbo timer can be a bit temperemental.

It *could* be a case of moisture ingress into the control unit for the remote starter.

As Solar Mike mentions the first step is to disconnect/disable the remote starter and see if the problems persist. If the don't then you've found your culprit, and at that point I'd suggest contacting the manufacturer/installer of the remote start system.

Comment: I HAVE seen a car do this : manual left in gear, no handbrake, with a separate starter solenoid mounted on the wing. The internal spring in the solenoid failed and the contactor bar dropped operating the starter - engine turned and fired : damaging the car and one other...